# a sliding up panel just like google maps app that have a middle state

Tags: java, android, slideup

I want the Exact thing that Google Map app has for its business pages.

I'm using SlidingUpPanel ([lib](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel)) in my project. I have a map activity and I want to have a sliding up panel like google map with a fab button on top of my sliding panel.
[this is what i want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArQ2Q.png)

This is my layout XML:

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/SlidingPanel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="96dp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp"
sothree:umanoAnchorPoint="0.7"
sothree:umanoParallaxOffset="100dp"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/NestedScrollView">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/SlidingPanelToolbar"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary">
            </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/aaa"
                android:background="@android:color/white"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that this slide up doesn't have any middle state. it is either up or closed but I need a half-open state too.

Comment: Edit your question and include what exactly you need. It is hard to answer such not specific questions. What is it that you don't like about the library. What feature does it lack that you need?

Comment: @spork I did edit the question

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you need is a [BottomSheet](https://material.io/design/components/sheets-bottom.html) UI pattern.

It was added to the [Google's Design Support Library](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Design-Support-Library) in [version 23.2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/02/android-support-library-232.html)

[Here](http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/how-to-use-bottom-sheets-with-the-design-support-library--cms-26031) is a sample tutorial on how to use it.